# Listening for change inside compund view

Tags: java, android, xml, view, listener

I have an Activity that displays five custom compound views. Within these views there are a couple of EditTexts and a Spinner.

When anything changes within any of the five compound views, I want my Activity to fire a method. So I need a listener in my Activity that listens for any change inside the Compound views. I would prefer not having to check every single control inside the compound views, but just notify my Activity that a view has changed state somehow.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: It could be that the spinner has changed values, or that anything is entered in the EditTexts

Comment: override dispatchKeyEvent dispatchTouchEvent etc

Comment: @pskink would that be a better and simpler approach than to implement an observer-pattern?

Comment: but what do you want to observe? you would need to setup a bunch of listeners for every child but it's what you wanted to avoid

Comment: Maybe it is. My first approach was to implement a notifier in the compound view and a listener in the activity. That way I could just call the notify() method in the view when anything is changed. But I guess that's a bit more mess

Comment: still you can do it that way,  just call your listener's method in dispatch* method

Comment: Thanks. I actually ended up writing a simple observer interface. Made it slicj and simple